# Shared Memory in C, Issue with shmdt ,it throws me invalid argument

Tags: c, pointers

I have a structure like this

```
 typedef struct {
int id;     //Client ID
int size;   //Memory Size
int mem;    //ID obtained from shmid
int  buf;   //shared memory var
} Segm;

 Segm segms[10];
int count_s = 0;

     int * buffer; /* shared buffer */
        /* we declared to zone to share */
       buffer =  shmat (mem, (char *)0, 0);
       if (buffer == NULL) {
          fprintf (stderr, "Error reserve shared memory \n");
          return -1; 
       }
        segms[count_s].mem = mem;
        segms[count_s].buf = *buffer;
```

The code above, creates the shared memory for the current structure, and it works fine, but when i try to dettach the memory, shmdt throws me , invalid argument, i can't see why.

```
  int mem = segms[i].mem;

 /* detach from the segment: */
    if (shmdt(&segms[i].buf) == -1) {
              perror("[SHMservice] Error: shmdt");
              result = -2;
    }

   shmctl (mem, IPC_RMID, (struct shmid_ds *)NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the wrong value to `shmdt`: you're giving it the address of the `buf` member of your struct, not the pointer you stored in that `int` variable.

To fix it, first fix your structure. The type of `buf` should be `void*` (or `int*` if that's more practical for you). Then fix the attach code to set it:

```
segms[count_s].buf = buffer;
```

If you go with `void*`, you should adjust the type of `buffer` too.

Then you can `shmdt(segms[i].buff)`.

Comment: Solved! many thanks, i declare a pointer to int for the buffer.